# Matrix Subtract like Matrix Multiplication in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, matrix, matrix-multiplication

This is my first post I usually found all my answers in the archives, but having a hard time with this one, thanks for the help!

I have two matrix A and B.  Performing a matrix multiplication operation is trivial using tf.matmult.  But I want to do matrix subtract similar to how matrix multiplication works. Eg if I have.

```
A = tf.constant([[1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1],[1,2,3,4,5,6],[4,3,2,1,6,5]])
B = tf.constant([[1,3,1],[2,1,1]])

#B*A
X = tf.matmult(B,A)
>>>X = [[8,10,12,15,24,24],[7,7,7,9,17,13]]
```

What I want to do is do a similar operation like matmult, but instead of multiply I want subtract and square. Eg...

for x<sub>11</sub>, where the subscript 11 is row 1, column 1 of matrix X.

= (-b<sub>11</sub> + a<sub>11</sub>)<sup>2</sup> + (-b<sub>12</sub> + a<sub>21</sub>)<sup>2</sup> + (-b<sub>13</sub> + a<sub>31</sub>)<sup>2</sup>

and

x<sub>12</sub> = (-b<sub>11</sub> + a<sub>12</sub>)<sup>2</sup> + (-b<sub>12</sub> + a<sub>22</sub>)<sup>2</sup> + (-b<sub>13</sub> + a<sub>32</sub>)<sup>2</sup>

and so on similar to how matrix multiplication works.

So if we take matrix A and B above and perform the operation described above (call it matmultsubtract), we get,

tf.matmultsubtract(B,A) gives:

[[(-1+1)<sup>2</sup>+(-3+1)<sup>2</sup>+(-1+4)<sup>2</sup>, (-1+1)<sup>2</sup>+(-3+2)<sup>2</sup>+(-1+3)<sup>2</sup>,...],

[(-2+1)<sup>2</sup>+(-1+1)<sup>2</sup>+(-1+4)<sup>2</sup>, (-2+1)<sup>2</sup>+(-1+2)<sup>2</sup>+(-1+3)<sup>2</sup>, ...]]

This isn't that hard if working with numpy arrays (you can use two nested for loops) by iterating manually rather than np.matmult, but tensorflow has a problem with for loops and I'm not sure how to do it.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, why do you need this? I have never seen someone asking to do that... Matrix multiplication is the way it is because that's how we would compose linear operators, but why would you need a similar structure for [squared] subtraction?

Comment: I imagine it has something to do with MSE. With that in mind I'm wondering what you want to do because there might be a better way of doing it

Comment: You can do that using `tf.while_loop`, it's just a bit complex-ish. Let me give it a go

Comment: @Fred In my case, I want to implement a [RBF kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radial_basis_function) using two matrices (sets of column vectors) as input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying a vectorization operation that may not be taken as matrix subtract.

```
# shape=(2,3,6)
B_new = tf.tile(tf.expand_dims(B,axis=-1),multiples=[1,1,A.shape[1]])
# shape=(2,3,6)
A_new = tf.tile(tf.expand_dims(A,axis=0),multiples=[B.shape[0],1,1])
# shape=(2,6)
result = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(A_new - B_new),axis=1)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(result))

[[13  5  1  2 33 25]
 [10  6  6  9 42 42]]
```